# Why is array in collection view getting multiplied by amount of sections?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uicollectionview

When I want to see an array in a collection view in swift, it gets multiplied by the amount of sections in the collection view. Why is this and how do I stop it?

```
let numbers = ["one", "two", "three"]

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3;
    }
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let theCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "theCell", for: indexPath) as! cell

for number in numbers {
            print("\(number)")
        }

return theCell

}
```

I hoped that it would return:

> one
>
> two
>
> three

but instead it returned:

> one
>
> two
>
> three
>
> one
>
> two
>
> three
>
> one
>
> two
>
> three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have three cells per section, and assuming you have only one section, `collectionView(_:cellForItemAt:)` gets called three times. Each time you are printing all the elements of the `numbers` array. To only print the element corresponding to the current index, replace the for loop by:

```
print(numbers[indexPath.row])
```